# Understanding connector footprint on PCB

Tags: pcb, connector, footprint

I wish to make a footprint for Amphenol GSB343K33HR connector that I am using on my PCB. I am however having difficulty in understanding the PCB layout that has been mentioned by the manufacturer in his drawing. The drawing is present at the following location: http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Amphenol%20PDFs/GSB343K33HR_dwg.pdf

[image]

The rest seems fine to me but I am unable to understand what the oblong parts on the layout edges are. Are they through-hole or SMD pads? Also what would be the X- and Y- widths of the oblong parts. The '2-0.50' is not clear to me.

Comment: Post a screen-grab of the connector in your post to save everyone having to look it up and find it in the document.

Comment: Screen grab added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oblong holes are for solder tabs, which help anchor the connector to the PCB. They are plated through-holes. The 2-0.50 probably means 2x 0.50 width (there are two solder tabs, and each hole is 0.5mm wide). The dimensions of the holes and pads are called out in the drawing -- 0.50mm wide by 1.30mm long. The outer "ring" might be for the pad (the previous dimensions were for the hole itself). It looks very narrow though, I would make the solder pad as wide as you possibly can without creating clearance problems between them and your other pads. Keep the hole the same size though.

Comment: So for the through holes in the Pad Designer I would have to mention the drill hole sizes and the rest of the layers for the pads?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. You did not mention what CAD software you are using, so I can't tell you exactly how to do it in the program you're using. Most PCB CAD software allows you to define a hole/slot by calling out the hole width and length as well as the pad width and length, and it is treated as a single part. Without more information from you, I can't tell you if that's the case or if it will be more complicated for you.

Comment: I'm using Cadence (v16.5) Pad Designer.

Comment: Sometimes these can be seen as an extra "pins" of the connector, if modeled properly, which you might leave either unconnected or better connected to a chassis net.

Answer (score 0):

I think the '2-0.5' may be trying to convey two 0.5mm diameter drill holes, one at each end of the slot. (I don't recognise the notation in that drawing, but I believe I have seen similar diagrams for USB 2 connectors which state drill diameters for the end of slots)

Looking at the rest of the drawing, the material is 0.3mm thick, and the tab that fits into that slot is 0.9mm long.

So 0.5mm/2 radius holes, on 0.8mm centres (1.3mm length slot) would take that tab quite snugly.

Then the 1.9mm slot annotation is recommending 0.3mm width track around the slot ((1.9mm-1.3mm)/2 = 0.3mm). That seems okay.